# Let $0=A \in M_3(\mathbb{C})$ be a Hermitian matrix. Show that $A^k=0$ for all positive integers $k$.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, hermitian-matrices

I'm stuck on this problem. I am not sure why the question is only about $M_{3\times3}(\Bbb C)$. Isn't this problem true for $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is the $n \times n$ matrix $0$, then $A^k = 0$ for all $k$.  Hint: in fact $A B = 0$ for any $n \times n$ matrix $B$.  I don't know why your instructor decided to take $n=3$ (maybe making it "less abstract"?), nor why "Hermitian" was mentioned.

Comment: A formatting tip: if you want text like \mathbb{C} to produce $\Bbb C$, you'll need to enclose it in dollar signs on this website. See more information about formatting in math mode for this site [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).